# how to send CURL code using php via simple html form

Tags: php, curl

I have this CURL code & i need to send this code with input data using php.

CURL Code:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"apiKey": "43wrxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "message":"MessageValue", "title":"TitleValue", "platform":"android", "publicKey": "wxxxx", "live": "false"}' https://push.xxxxx.io/api/send
```

I need to add **Message** and **Title** in the code then send the code using php.

Example form:

```
<html>
<head><title>Test Form</title></head>

<body>
<form action="server.php" method="post">
  Message: <input type="text" name="message"><br>
  Title: <input type="text" name="title"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>

</html>
```

How i can do that using **PHP** ?

Thank you!

Comment: You could submit the data via AJAX and process the data on a server-side PHP script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['Submit']){
$ch = curl_init( 'https://push.xxxxx.io/api/send');
$data=array('api_key'=>'43wrxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx','message'=>$_POST['message']);//You can enter more data
$payload = json_encode( $data );//encode data to json
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json'));
# Return response instead of printing.
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
# Send request.
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
# Print response.
}else{
die('error'); // invalid entry
}
?>
```

This may be the server.php file in your system.. You can access form data by $_POST[{name}]. Append it with API values needed then encode and sent it via curl.